# React Native navigate from Tabnavigator to stack navigator

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-router, react-redux

I have a tab navigator where `MyHomeScreen` is the initial view. 
In my Homescreen i have another component with an action to navigate to another screen but when i press it is not navigating to `AnotherscreenWithouttab`.

**MyHomeScreen**

```
render() {
    const navigation = this.props.navigation;
    const {navigate} = this.props.navigation;
    return (
        <Actionscreen
             navigation={navigation}
        />
        </View>
    );
}
```

**ActionScreen**

```
render() {    
    const {navigate} = this.props.navigation;

    return (
        <View >
            <TouchableOpacity 
                onPress={ () => navigate('AnotherscreenWithouttabRoute', { param1: 'Route-1' }) }
            ><Text>go to another screen</Text></TouchableOpacity>
        </View>    
    );
}
```

**TabNavigator**

```
  const DashboardTab = TabNavigator(
        {
            Home: {
                screen: MyHomeScreen,
                path: '',
            },
            People: {
                screen: FeedScreen,
                path: 'cart',
            }
        }
class DashboardTabComponent extends Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
    }

    render() {

        const {
            navigation,
            screenProps
        } = this.props;

        return(
            <DashboardTab
                //navigation={navigation}
                screenProps={screenProps}
                //screenProps={this.state}
            />
        );
    }

}
```

**router.js**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Text, View, ScrollView, TouchableOpacity, AsyncStorage, ActivityIndicator, Image, StyleSheet } from 'react-native';
import { DrawerNavigator, DrawerItems, DrawerView, StackNavigator, TabNavigator, Header } from 'react-navigation';


import { HomeComponent } from "./Home/HomeComponent";

import { AboutusComponent } from "./Aboutus/AboutusComponent";

import { AnotherscreenWithouttabComponent } from "./AnotherscreenWithouttab";

import FeedAndSearchTab from "./feed/FeedAndSearchTab";
import { DetailsScreen1 } from "./Details/DetailsScreen1";
import { DetailsScreen2 } from "./Details/DetailsScreen2";

import * as css from "./Styles/Styles";
import { Button, Icon } from "react-native-elements";

//
// tabs
//

const nav_tab = TabNavigator(
    // route config
    {
        DetailsRoute1: { screen: DetailsScreen1 },
        DetailsRoute2: { screen: DetailsScreen2 },
    },
    // navigator config
    {
        lazy: true, // render the tabs lazily
        tabBarPosition: 'bottom', // where are the tabs shown
        backBehavior: 'none', // back button doesn't take you to the initial tab
        tabBarOptions: css.tabs
    },
);




//
// stack
//
export const AppNavigator = (isIntroRead = false, isSignedIn = false) => {
    return StackNavigator(
    // route config
    {
        HomeRoute: { screen: HomeComponent, path: 'home', }, // this is displayed first

        AboutusRoute: { screen: AboutusComponent },

        AnotherscreenWithouttabRoute: { screen: AnotherscreenWithouttabComponent , path: 'appointment/schedule', },

    },
    // navigator config
    {
        //headerMode: 'none', // this removes the navigation header
        initialRouteName: isIntroRead ? 'HomeRoute' : 'IntroRoute', // HomeRoute /IntroRoute AppointmentScheduleRoute
        navigationOptions: ({ navigation, screenProps }) => {
            return {
                headerTitle: <Title
                                navigation={navigation}
                                titleName={'Doctor On Call'}
                            />, // label text // headerTitle: "Hi",
                ...css.header, // other styling
                headerLeft: <TitleAndIcon navigation={navigation} />,
                headerRight: <MenuIcon
                                navigation={navigation}
                                screenProps={screenProps}
                             />,
                header: (props) => <ImageHeader {...props} />,
            }
        },
        cardStyle:{backgroundColor: '#FFFFFF', shadowOpacity: 0, shadowColor: 'transparent', }
    }
    );
};

//export default AppNavigator;
```

Comment: Can you give us the StackNavigator you are using please

Comment: your 'AnotherscreenWithouttab' route must be defined in your StackNavigator

Comment: @GabrielDiez I have added my main router.js file which contain my stack navigation

Comment: @chetan I have already added the rout in stack navigation,  please take a look on the router.js file i have added

Comment: @GabrielDiez sorry it was a type error when i tried to copy paste the code here. I was using the same "AnotherscreenWithouttabRoute".

Comment: your `DashboardTab` and `nav_tab` not exist in other part of your code, why?

Comment: @Val Which part ?

Comment: 1. Please post the error you are facing. 2. you can't put text directly in TouchableOpacity, it should throw you run time error(please look at your ActionScreen )

Comment: @chetan That was a typo error when i tried to copy the code here. An Iam not getting any error in the console but the it is not going to the other screen.